# Kohana 3.2 Passing Query Variables to Index Page

Tags: php, http, redirect, kohana

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$this->request->redirect("/?message=".HTML::entities($message));
```

However, this is resulting in my index controller dying on me (ie 500 internal server error, no stacktrace). Is this a no no?

Comment: How about using Request::query() ? Like: `$this->request->query('message', $message)->redirect()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No stacktrace while 500 error in Kohana indicates some low level error (PHP or Web Server error). It could be object properties or method Visibility issue or something.

Otherwise Kohana would generate for you exception explanation (when `errors => true` is set in `bootstrap.php` in `Kohana::init()` section).

Inspect your server error log file for last errors. You'll find solution there.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function action_index()
{
    $to = arr::get($_GET,'to' , 'world');
    $this->response->body('hello, '.urldecode($to).'!');
}

public function action_jump() {
    $to = urlencode('Tony Stark');
    $this->request->redirect('/?to=' . $to);
}
```